# How to do Multiple map condition in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am using the reactjs javascript. I want two map conditions to perform into single operation.

I have one map like this:
`{fname.map(fileName => (<label>{fileName}</label>}}`

Another one is:

```
{fname.document.map(fileName => (<label>{fileName.documentName.map(sff=>sff)}</label>))}
```

`fname` is a array:

```
const [fname, setfname] = useState([]);
```

I am using fname in condition already:

```
{fname ? 
<>
//something already goes here
</>
:
<>
//Here is only one condition is working. I want to make it work one map at a time. If one fails other should work.
</>
}
```

Basically what I want is: if one condition map fails then other one should work. Both of them working but I want to make it work only one at a time either of two.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not best solution but you do it with nested condition.

Like

```
{fname ? 
    <>
    //something already goes here
    </>
    :
    <>

    //Here is only one condition is working. I want to make it work one map at a time. If one fails other should work.

       //New condition
    otherCondition ? <></> : <> </>
    </>
    }
```

Comment: i need only condition to work. Anyways, your answer is not working. Any other solution?